# Visa Family Permit

Tags: visas, uk, family, yemeni-citizens

Good Morning. I am writing to you to ask you about entry to the UK to visit my wife's sister. I am from Yemen and I am married to a Polish citizen. At the moment I live in Germany and I have a Family Member resident card in the paper Under Law No. 10 form.

Can I enter the UK on this card without a visa or permit member? If not, when I will apply can I send some of my documents in German language?

Comment: Will you be traveling to the UK with your Polish spouse?

Answer (score 6):

> Can I travel to the UK on this card without a visa or family permit?

Only if you are traveling to the UK with your wife or joining her there.  If she will not be in the UK then you need a standard visitor visa.

> If not, when I apply for the family permit can I send some of my documents in the German language?

You have no use for a family permit, because you can only enter the UK with a family permit if you are traveling with your wife.  But in that case you can use your article 10 residence card.  Instead you need a standard visitor visa.

All documents submitted for UK visa applications must be in English or Welsh.  Any documents in German must be submitted with a translation.